# Thank-you letters sends email immediately

Tags: civimail, contributions

we are emailing the receipts of last year's contributions. From "find contributions" we select "Thank-you letters - print or email" and then "Send emails where possible. Generate printable PDFs for contacts who cannot receive email.".

I thought it was using the CiviMail component to send (and its configurations, like Mailer Batch Limit, Mailer Throttle Time), but **emails are sent immediately**, occupying a lot of memory resources. And my **SMTP server rejects them as spam**.

Have I forgotten a configuration? Or is it the behaviour for this process?
Or is there another way to send receipts of last year's contributions?
Or should I use SparkPost which distributes the email delivery?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues at hand here:

CiviCRM does not use the CiviMail/it's mailing feature for the thank you letters. In many case that would make a lot of sense but I guess when the feature was built no one considered using it for so many emails. You may use another extension that sends contribution receipts via CiviCRM's mailing feature such as this one: https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.donrec

The other issue is that you should probably configure your mail server in a way that it is less likely to be classified as spam. There should be many questions & answers regarding such configurations here on Stackexhcange, most important would probably be so set up proper spf records. This will not necessarily solve the problem described above (e.g. Mailer Batch Limits or resource usage).

Comment: Hi @Fabian, thank you, you have been very kind. I'm trying [SYSTOPIA Donation Receipts Extension](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.donrec) and I think it is perfect for italian law. I'm using CiviCRM on Wordpress and it seems to work well except pdf view.
Regards SMTP problem, my IP was added to some blacklists because a very large number of emails was sent in same time slot....of course :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - happy to help ^^ If you are having issues with wordpress using the extension, please create an issue on github. I think there is currently some work being done on some WP issues so check if there is already an issue for your problem.